# False Position Method (help needed)

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, nonlinear-functions

I'm attempting to write a code to find the root of non-linear equations using the false position method.
I'm done with my code, but I still have a problem.
For example, if I know that the root is between 5 and 6.
so I enter the upper limit as 7 and the lower at 6.
I still get the root.
I don't understand how the false position method converges even when the two initial guesses are not bracketing the root.

Here is my code:

```
void main()
{   
    std::cout << "Enter the First Limit: " << std::endl;
    double x1;
    std::cin >> x1;

    std::cout << "Enter The Second Limit: " << std::endl;
    double x2;
    std::cin >> x2;

    std::cout << "\nThe root = " << iteration(x1,x2); << std::endl;
}

double f(double x)
{
  return pow(x,3) - 8*pow(x,2)+12*x-4;
}

// Evaluating the closer limit to the root
// to make sure that the closer limit is the
// one that moves and the other one is fixed

inline bool closerlimit(double u, double l)
{
  return fabs(f(u)) > fabs(f(l)));
}

double iteration(double u, double l)
{
  double s=0;
  for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
  {
      s = u - ((f(u)*(l-u)) / (f(l)-f(u)));
      if (closerlimit(u,l))
        l = s;
      else
        u = s;
  }

  return s;
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is old. Please use `int main()` instead

Comment: Do you have a reference for the method you are using? It is different from the ["method of false position"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MethodofFalsePosition.html) mentioned on Mathworld, in which x_1 remains constant throughout the process (unlike your 'u').

Comment: Hmm, `void main()` is not "old" in C++. As far as I know, it's *never* been consistent with the standard.

Comment: @Cody `void main()` is mainly used in old C++ code. And a modern compiler will give you an error for `void main()` 
@AKenawy I've allowed me to make your code a bit shorter so it will be easier to answer.

Comment: Um, BTW, there is no root of [x^3-8x^2+12x-4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-8x%5E2%2b12x-4) between 5 and 6; there *is* a root between 6 and 7, which is what you're getting. Check your maths. :-)

Comment: In your method as written, s is not always between l and u, which suggests something is seriously wrong. (It gives the 6.156… answer even when the interval is (5,6), and sometimes gives rubbish answers.) Look up the method again.

Comment: Are you sure you want (l-u) and not (u-l)?

Answer (score 1):

Your function plot and roots:

[image]

Comment: guys, i mentioned that right in the question. I know that there is a root between 6 and 7, but if you enter the limits 5 and 6, you will still get your root. I don't know how this happens. I thought that false position doesn't converges unless the limits are bracketing the root.

Comment: You say one thing, but mean something else. You clearly said that you knew the root was between 5 and 6 and that you used the interval 6 to 7. Please edit your question to reflect what you really mean.

Answer (score 0):

But the interval IS bracketing the root.

Comment: no, f(5) and f(6) are negative, so they are not bracketing the root. It's also apparent from the graph in the first answer

Comment: I meant the interval 6 to 7, which you said you were using. Not 5 to 6.